# $routeParams AngularJs not giving the Id back

Tags: angularjs-routing

I've try to figured out how it work with $routeParams in angular which i have an json object like this:
`[
    {
        "pId": "DE123",
        "name": "Gogo",
        "email": "gogo@gogo.de",
        "roles": "Administrator"
    },{
        "pId": "DE124",
        "name": "Giant Ape",
        "email": "giant@ape.de",
        "roles": "Stuff"
    },{
        "pId": "DE125",
        "name": "Jonnie",
        "email": "jonnie@goodboy.de",
        "roles": "Redaktur"
    },{
        "pId": "DE126",
        "name": "Supermen",
        "email": "supermen@isdead.de",
        "roles": "Redaktur"
    }
]`

and my controller is:

```
.controller('usersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
$scope.msg = 'I come from Users Controller';
$http.get('dataModel/users.json').then(function(res){
    $scope.users = res.data;
    $scope.users = $routeParams.pId;
})
```

})

and my route is:

```
        .when('/users/:pId', {
        templateUrl: 'tpl/viewUsr.html',
        controller: 'usersCtrl'
    })
```

and my tpl/viewUsr.html is:

```
<h3>Hello User {{users[0].pId}}</h3>
<p>i come from {{users[0].pId}}</p>
```

somehow the view does not get the pId from the Controller. what i do wrong? Thank you So much for any kind of idea or help.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!!

Here we go. i did a mistake on the Controller it should be like this.

```
.controller('usersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
$scope.msg = 'I Come from Users Controller';
$http.get('dataModel/users.json').success(function(res){
    $scope.users = res;
    $scope.viewUsr = $routeParams;
    //$routeParams = res.data.pId;
}) }])
```

and in the view:

```
<h3>View User #{{viewUsr.pId}}</h3>
<p>Hello User #{{viewUsr.pId}}</p>
```

have fun if someone have the same problem as i have :) thanks for everyone for whatching out bit of my problem. :)